# Xamarin Forms Xaml Converter: Bindable property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

In Xamarin Forms I'm trying to create a xaml converter with properties.
This is to be used, for example, to show values from a list in different ways, based on a code behind property.

I based my code on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29869734.

**Converter:**

```
namespace App2.Converters
{
    class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public int ConvParam { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return $"value: {value} - ConvParam: {ConvParam}";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:App2.Converters"
         x:Class="App2.MainPage"
         x:Name="MainPageXaml">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <conv:MyConverter x:Key="cnv" ConvParam="{Binding Source={Reference MainPageXaml}, Path=PropParam}" />
    <!--<conv:MyConverter x:Key="cnv" ConvParam="333" />-->
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={Reference MainPageXaml}, Path=PropVal}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={Reference MainPageXaml}, Path=PropParam}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={Reference MainPageXaml}, Path=PropVal, Converter={StaticResource cnv}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public int PropVal { get; set; } = 111;
    public int PropParam { get; set; } = 222;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The goal is to bind ConvParam of my converter to PropParam in code behind.

But if I use:

```
<conv:MyConverter x:Key="cnv" ConvParam="{Binding Source={Reference MainPageXaml}, Path=PropParam}" />
```

the error **Position 10:39. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ConvParam', or mismatching type between value and property** is shown and the app doesn't compile.

The property **ConvParam** itself is recognized inside xaml: if I replace the above line with

```
<conv:MyConverter x:Key="cnv" ConvParam="333" />
```

everything works.

The binding expression I used (*{Binding Source={Reference MainPageXaml}, Path=PropParam}*) actually works, if used as source for the text property of a label:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={Reference MainPageXaml}, Path=PropParam}" />
```

But if I use it in Resources, It doesn't work.

Comment: You can not set a binding to a property that is not a BindableProperty! You have to define ConvParam as a BindableProperty. See https://xamarinhelp.com/bindable-properties-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Also, you should better try using the built-in ConverterParameter property instead defining your own. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#binding-converter-parameters

Comment: Thank you Julipan, I modified my converter and defined ConvParam as BindableProperty and it worked. I don't use ConverterParameter because... it's not a BindableProperty! I will modify my question to show the working code, but I'd like to give you credits for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You can post your answer and accept it, which will help more people .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to **Julipan** I could make it work!

As he pointed out, ConvParam must be a BindableProperty, so I modified my converter to inherit from BindableObject and defined ConvParam as BindableProperty.

**Converter:**

```
namespace App2.Converters
{
    class MyConverter : BindableObject, IValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ConvParamProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ConvParam), typeof(int), typeof(MyConverter));

        public int ConvParam
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ConvParamProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ConvParamProperty, value); }
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return $"value: {value} - ConvParam: {ConvParam}";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```