# I'm getting the error "No property,BindableProperty, or event found "x" or type mismatch". Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a converter. I've made a property in the converter so I can bind data to it from the view model.
I've done the following in the Converter:

```
private List<InfoField> _fields = new List<InfoField>();
public List<InfoField> Fields
{
    get { return _fields;}
    set { _fields = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
}
```

In the View Model I have

```
public List<InfoField> FilteredFields { get; set; }
```

And in the XAML I have the following:

```
    <ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" Fields="{Binding FilteredFields}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

I'm not quite sure what I am missing or have done wrong.
I followed the 19 vote answer on the following article to get to this point:
[Use Binding as ConverterParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820639/use-binding-as-converterparameter)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: does the error message literally say "x" or are you paraphrasing?  If the message is literally "x" then you need to check your `xmlns` declarations.  If not, then please post the exact error message

Comment: I was paraphrasing. Sorry I didn't make that clearer. The exact error is this:
No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Fields", or mismatching type between value and property.

Comment: it sounds like you need to create a BindableProperty for Fields - the answer you linked to eludes to this but does not explicitly show how to do it.  The Xamarin docs have a good writeup on BindableProperties

Comment: @Jason I've added this line into my Converter, however I get a "Reference not set to an instance of an object error.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with that or if I've missed anything out.

public static readonly BindableProperty FieldsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Fields), typeof(List<InfoField>), typeof(IndexConverter));

Comment: you need to figure out what is causing the null ref.  Fire up the debugger